# How to keep case with RegExp?

Tags: javascript, regex, actionscript-3

How do I keep the case when replacing words with a RegExp? I'm using this expression:

```
token = "word";
text = "The Cow jumped over the moon. And the Dish ran away with the Spoon.";
value = text.replace(/\b\w\b/g, token);
//value = text.replace(/\b\w{1,}\b/g, token.charAt(0) + token.charAt(token.length-1));
```

// this results in

```
value == "word word word word word word. word word word word word word word word.";
```

// what i want is

```
value == "Word Word word word word word. Word word Word word word word word Word.";
```

**Edit**:
The reg exp matches every word.

Comment: I believe you will need to run two regexes, one for the capitalised words, and again for uncapitalised words. You'll have to be more specific too -- what if you have a "DIsh rAn AWAY witH the sPOON"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a conditional return within a replace function.

### Explicit Proper Noun

To filter only words that start with an uppercase letter:

```
token = "word";
text = "The Cow jumped over the moon. And the Dish ran away with the Spoon.";
value = text.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, function(instance) {
   if (instance.charAt(0) === instance.charAt(0).toUpperCase()) {
       return token.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + token.substr(1, token.length - 1);
   } else {
       return token;
   }
});

// Output: "Word Word word word word word. Word word Word word word word word Word."
```

### Mixed Case

If you want to detect mixed case too, use the condition `instance !== instance.toLowerCase()` (I changed the string to include mixed case words):

```
token = "word";
text = "The Cow juMped over the mOON. And the Dish ran away with the Spoon.";
value = text.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, function(instance) {
   if (instance !== instance.toLowerCase()) {
       return token.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + token.substr(1, token.length - 1);
   } else {
       return token;
   }
});

// Output: "Word Word Word word word Word. Word word Word word word word word Word."
```

Answer (score 1):

You can also do it in regex like this

```
str = str.replace(/\b\w+\b/g, function(m){ 
   return /^[A-Z]/.test(m) ? "Word" : "word" 
});
```

Comment: You still used a regexp: `/^[A-Z]/`. Also, splitting by space doesn't detect all word breaks (such as punctuation), or even all white space characters.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest doing it in two stages

```
/\b[A-Z][a-z]*\b/Word/g
```

then

```
/\b[a-z]*\b/word/g
```

warning -

- this simply ignores any words which are `MixedCase` and `ALLCAPS`.
- this method will break internationalisation / unicode support etc.